# Short story about perpetual historical tourism

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, androids

Trying to remember title/author of a story I read some years back. I probably read it in one of Gardner Dozois' collections, or another anthology, so I couldn't tell you the year of publication.

In a distant future, people spend their time as tourists in fantastic recreations of historical cities. A new city is created every once in a while, while the old ones are destroyed to make way for something new. The recreations are populated by realistic but not-quite-sentient synthetic humanoids. Our hero, whose memory of his own backstory is somewhat hazy, travels as the companion of a beautiful woman. Unlike the rest of society, she's likely to die (she lacks immortality, or is sick or something?) he eventually realized he's synthetic too, and then realizes he can save the life of his beloved by transferring her consciousness into a synthetic form like his.

The story was so richly atmospheric, I'd love to read it again. Anybody know what it was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be ['Sailing to Byzantium'](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40973) by Robert Silverberg. It was included in several of Gardner Dozois's collections.

Comment: That's it! Much thanks!